# Compiler uses char overload of Port.Write instead of byte

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to Port.Write a byte variable into an serial port but compiler still give me an error

> cannot convert byte to char[]

It looks that it uses wrong overload (char[],  int, int) instead of (byte, int, int). How to force compiler to use the right one?
This is my code:

```
private void sendbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte temp;
    temp = (byte) 0x01;
    //Wyslij(sndbox.Text);
    Wyslij(temp, 0, 1);
}
private void Wyslij(byte buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    try { Port.Write(buffer, offset, count); }
#if DEBUG
    catch { return; }
#else
    catch { MessageBox.Show( "Nie można zapisać do portu\nPrawdopodobnie port jest zamknięty."); }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload that accepts a `byte` parameter. There is an overload that accepts a `byte[]`: [`SerialPort.Write (Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx), but you would need to rewrite all your code.

```
private void sendbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte temp;
    temp = (byte)0x01;
    //Wyslij(sndbox.Text);
    Wyslij(new[] { temp }, 0, 1);
}

private void Wyslij(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    try { Port.Write(buffer, offset, count); }
#if DEBUG
    catch { return; }
#else
    catch { MessageBox.Show( "Nie można zapisać do portu\nPrawdopodobnie port jest zamknięty."); }
#endif
}
```